# Attempted to assign to readonly property on Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, poltergeist

I'm working on updating a `rails 3.2` app to `rails 4.2.10`, I've got almost everything worked out, unit tests and integration tests passing.

I'm having some issues with feature tests, I'm using `capybara 3.3.0` and `poltergeist 1.18.1` and it throws me error on `visit '/'`

I've looked at lots of issues on Stack regarding **Attemped to assign to readonly property** but none of them apply to my case here,

This is my stripped down spec file

```
require 'vcr'

Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 10

feature "Create something"  do
  include SpecHelpers
  include Acceptance

  before do
    setup_database
  end

  after do
    teardown_database
  end

  scenario "Creating a Consignment", :js => true do

    puts "Running with #{Capybara.current_driver}"

    VCR.use_cassette('cassette_name.yml') do      
      page.driver.resize(1000,2200) unless Capybara.current_driver == :selenium
      visit '/'
      expect(page).to have_content 'EMAIL'
      expect(page).to have_content 'PASSWORD'


    end
  end

end
```

This is my stripped down spec helper file

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'

require_relative '../config/environment.rb'

require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
require 'shoulda/matchers'
require 'redis'
require 'redis-namespace'
require 'resque'
require 'mock_redis'
require 'bcrypt'

Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    with.test_framework :rspec
    with.library :rails
  end
end

# rspec
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.deprecation_stream = 'log/deprecations.log'
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, :type => :controller
end

RSpec::Expectations.configuration.on_potential_false_positives = :nothing

BCrypt::Engine.cost = 1

if (ENV['DEBUG_CAP'])
  Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
  end
else
  Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
    Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {js_errors: true})
  end
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
end
Capybara.server_port = 31337

Capybara.server = :webrick

module SpecHelpers
  def setup_database
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  def teardown_database
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

end

module Acceptance

  VCR.configure do |c|
    require 'webmock'
    c.hook_into :webmock
    c.cassette_library_dir = 'fixtures/vcr_cassettes'
    c.allow_http_connections_when_no_cassette = true
    c.default_cassette_options = {:record => :new_episodes}
    c.ignore_request do |request|
      URI(request.uri).port == Capybara.server_port || request.uri=~/shutdown/ || request.uri=~/session/
    end
  end

  def wait_until(timeout = Capybara.default_max_wait_time)
    require "timeout"
    begin
      Timeout.timeout(timeout) do
        sleep(0.3)  until value = yield
        value
      end
    rescue => e
      save_screenshot "capybara_#{Time.now.to_i}.png"
      puts e.message
      puts e.backtrace
      raise e
    end

  end
end

require "rspec/mocks/standalone"
....
```

This is the error stack trace

```
Running with poltergeist
Error: Attempted to assign to readonly property.
r@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:22:3139
r@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:5:3551
http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:5:19730
http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:5:12707
s@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:4:20964
g@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:5:12573
http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:5:16265
http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:5:22205
c@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:6:4206
c@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:6:4206
http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:6:4884
$digest@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:6:7801
$apply@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:6:9410
http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:4:26430
a@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:4:26340
Z@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:4:26051
http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:7:28112
d@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:1:18351
fireWith@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:1:19152
ready@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:1:13970
wt@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:1:11347
Error: Attempted to assign to readonly property.
r@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:22:3139
r@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:5:3551
http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:5:19730
http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:5:12707
s@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:4:20964
g@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:5:12573
http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:5:16265
http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:5:22205
c@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:6:4206
c@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:6:4206
http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:6:4884
$digest@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:6:7801
$apply@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:6:9410
http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:4:26430
a@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:4:26340
Z@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:4:26051
http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:7:28112
d@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:1:18351
fireWith@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:1:19152
ready@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:1:13970
wt@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:1:11347
Error: Attempted to assign to readonly property.
r@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:22:3139
r@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:5:3551
http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:5:19730
http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:5:12707
s@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:4:20964
g@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:5:12573
http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:5:16265
http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:5:22205
c@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:6:4206
c@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:6:4206
http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:6:4884
$digest@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:6:7801
$apply@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:6:9410
http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:4:26430
a@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:4:26340
Z@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:4:26051
http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:7:28112
d@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:1:18351
fireWith@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:1:19152
ready@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:1:13970
wt@http://127.0.0.1:31337/lib/bfd57c67.components.js:1:11347
```

**Update 1**

Upon some debugging, it turns out that error gets thrown from [angularjs-bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/dalelotts/angularjs-bootstrap-datetimepicker) package when it tries to set `$render` to a function,

```
var ngModelController = $element.controller('ngModel')

var configuration = createConfiguration()
$scope.screenReader = configuration.screenReader

// Behavior
$scope.changeView = changeView
ngModelController.$render = $render --> in this line
```

Comment: Poltergeist uses PhantomJS as its "browser" which is basically equivalent to a 7 year old browser.  If you've upgraded your angularjs recently I would guess it's not compatible with Poltergeist (without a lot of transpiling and polyfilling).  You're going to have a much easier time if you just use headless Chrome with Selenium instead of Poltergeist.  Also using `Timeout.timeout` with anything but the most trivial code is a recipe for problems, use the Capybara provided waiting behaviors instead.

Comment: sadly we're still at `angularjs 1.2.9` and I am in the process of upgrading but that is another story, do you think it could be anything related to my update above ?

Comment: I would still say one of the components you're loading is using something not compatible with Poltergeist/PhantomJS - just swap to using headless Chrome with Selenium for headless testing, it has way less headaches.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole do you have any ideas why headless chrome times out on a click button but works if I let it run with the browser ?

Comment: Times out doing what? finding the element, calling click, waiting for a page change??  I have no way of knowing without actual detailed info (code, stacktrace, etc). To diagnose yourself use `save_and_open_screenshot` and see what the page looks like compared to what you expect it to look like.

Comment: Sorry if I haven't been clear but I mentioned "times out on a click button" and yes I saw your `save_and_open_screenshot` suggestion on another stackoverflow post and it looks like I need to resize my window, Thank you